# Video calls for 20+ members for free?

Tags: windows, gratis, macos, video-conferencing

I'm looking for free software for weekly video calls for 20 - 25 members and at least 3 hours duration of **continuous** video calls and it should be compatible with Mac os and Windows and should have screen share function.

What I've tried that did not suit requirements:

- **Zoom** - there is 40 minutes limit.
- **Skype** - up to 10 members
- **Hangouts** - up to 10 members

What I want to try, but I need more information:

- **Discord**. - Didn't find information about time limits and member limits.

Can you recommend any other free software for video conferencing?

Comment: Welcome Anna!  Our community welcomes your post, but it needs to be rewritten as a request for software or a web-app.  If you will, please take a look at other posts here and our help system, and you'll see examples and information that will help you write a great post!  Thanks again, and welcome!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS should it run on, how much may it cost. And please adjust the title as well so it asks for software, as RockPaper already pointed out.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCaske I edited the question, please let me know if now it is ready to be posted. Thanks

Comment: Anna, it's starting to look great.  All it needs now is the maximum duration of the calls and the operating system(s).

Comment: I'm new to this site, but after the edition, this looks fine and justified (for the present context, for the tech scenario evolutions), I would also want to find equivalent apps. Is this going to be reopened or should the OP create a new one with this content?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I made all edits. Can it be posted?

Comment: Yes!  Thank you Anna!  I added 2 more tags for you and re-opened your great question.  :)

Comment: [This page](https://alternativeto.net/software/zoom-cloud-meetings/?license=free) shows software that fits your requirements. I know people that use Jitsi for university. I have not tried it myself, though as I am happy with Zoom and Teams. But those 2 are both paid.

Answer (score 2):

When you write "free software" it seems you really mean free-of-charge services.

I can recommend to use Free Software (a.k.a. Open Source), which means software that is both free-of-charge and free-from-control - i.e. software that is bound by ethically responsible ownership rules.

Most famous Free Software tool for video conferencing is Jitsi Meet.
It is a tool, not a service.  Multiple providers offer services using this same tool.
You can see a list of community-run Jitsi Meet services [here](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/community/community-instances).

Less famous, but equally good, is the Free Software tool [BigBlueButton](https://bigbluebutton.org/).  I am unaware if there is a list somewhere of services using BBB - one that I am aware of is [Senfcall](https://senfcall.de/en/) - free of charge, just requires you send them an email requesting access (and then you can create video rooms where *you* control access - it is not that all your participants need to get special access).

Yet another, more lightweight, video conferencing tool is backend [Mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/) using e.g. frontend [multiparty-meeting](https://github.com/havfo/multiparty-meeting).  One service using that combo is [letsmeet.no](https://letsmeet.no/).

Even more lightweight - and my personal favorite -
is backend [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/)
and e.g. frontend [Jangouts](https://github.com/jangouts/jangouts).
You are welcome to try use my service using that combo,
at https://live.jones.dk/

All of these services are - as far as I am aware - free for use however long you like, and should work with 20+ users if your bandwidth can keep up with that (otherwise you may need to limit amount of users with video enabled).